# Quit waiting on user input

Tags: bash, console, tui

I am trying to implement a waiting time the user can choose to skip by pressing any key. Also it must not print anything on the terminal as I am using it to display a progress bar.
I am having difficulty to catch and test user input with the further difficulty to it must not induce more delay in the total waiting time.

Here is what I have at the moment :

```
read -t 0 input </dev/tty1
   if [[ $input -ne "" ]]; then
exit 0
fi
```

And that is inside a loop that update the progress bar.
It succeeds not to add more delay or print unwanted lines but it doesn't fulfill its function.

-t 0 not to add further delay

reading from "/dev/tty1" not to add unwanted lines

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, it's the zero that's messing you up. If you change it for a very low number like .01, it will work. You can stream line it even further like this:

```
if $(read -t.01 -sn1); then exit 0; fi
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `$()` there. Just `if read ...`. You might also explain the `-s` and `-n` option.

Comment: that would still add delay

Comment: Ok, I validate the answer because it's really close to what I was trying and it is simple. Finally, I removed the sleep time of my loop and put it in the read timeout in place.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run two things in **parallel.**

1. Read the input waiting 5 sec (say)
2. Update the progress bar ( showing 5 seconds are finishing up )

To achieve this, do not put the `read` command inside the loop.

Instead, do something like this :

```
for i in {1..10}; do sleep 0.5s; echo ${i}0; done | zenity --progress --auto-close --text="waiting for input...5sec" 2>/dev/null &  
read -t 5 asd && kill $!
```

( put the above two lines to a file (say abc.sh) and run it `bash abc.sh` )

Explanation :

The first command ( to update the progress bar )is sent to background with **&** . If read command if finished first, `kill $!` will close the progress bar.

Note: Checkout  [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). That would help you do more stuffs in parallel.